# Pass DB Connection parameters to a Kettle a.k.a PDI table Input step dynamically from Excel

Tags: excel, parameters, pentaho, kettle

I have a requirement such that whenever i run my Kettle job, the database connection parameters must be taken dynamically from an excel source on each run.

Say i have an excel with column names : HostName, Username, Database, Password.

i want to pass these connection parameters to my table input step dynamically whenever the job runs.

This is what i was trying to do.

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can achieve this by

- reading the DB connection parameters from a source (e.g. Excel or in my example a CSV file)
- storing the parameters in variables
- using the variables in your connection setting.

Proceed as follows

- Create another transformation for setting the variables (you cannot do this in the same transformation that uses it):

[image: Transformation for setting the variables]

In the *Set Variables* element configure the variables:

[image: Configuring the variables]

- In the element reading/writing your data create a new connection and set the connection parameters using `${variable_name}`. Note that you have to blindly write `${password}` into the appropriate field. Also note that this may be a security issue because the value may show up as plain text in log files!

[image: Configuring the DB connection]

- In your job call the variable transformation first and then the functional part:

[image: Job]

Comment: Thank You Marcus. It works absolutely fine now. Thanks a lot.

Regards,

Comment: @Marcus will the job run for every row in the connexions' csv file input ?

Comment: Thanks @Marcus. Do you know if I can set a variable for a checkbox property? I mean, to set the "Use .. to Separate Schema ...", for example.
I need to set "Use Integrated Security" for MS SqlServer (Native) with Native (JDBC) driver, and change connection for different environments.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the XLS input and the Set Variables step. Define your variables as being valid in the Root job and you can use them in subsequent jobs, as long as they're called by the same root job, when defining the connection.

The "Copy rows to result" and "Get rows from result" are used to send information (rows of data) from one transformation to the next transformation or job in the same parent job. They're not used to send data between steps, that's what the hops are for.