# Connecting DB Connection from properties file outside the Kettle is not working

Tags: sql, database-connection, kettle

I am trying to remove DB Connection from `ktr file` and I am trying to connect to DBConnection by using the properties file which contains information about the connection. I used this link as reference;

[Pass DB Connection parameters to a Kettle a.k.a PDI table Input step dynamically from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491072/pass-db-connection-parameters-to-a-kettle-a-k-a-pdi-table-input-step-dynamicall).

I followed all the steps but I am not able to get the required output.

I want to connect to the database using properties file and have to excute the SQL using the DB defined in the properties file and the output has to be transfered into the output(Excel,csv,output-table etc).

Comment: Which error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

1- A Index job for start all (is my way)

This job call a transformation whose job is to load the connection data to the database

[image: Index]

2- The transformation that load the connection data pass this variables like parameters

[image: Variables]

3- The middle job is only for repeat the process if is necessary, only work like a bridge, pass the parameters

[image: Middle]

4- In this transformation does all DB work

[image: Select]

5- The datasource look like this.

[image: datasource]

PS: sorry for my poor english :(