# Pentaho Kettle- run check db connections without stopping job

Tags: kettle, pdi

I have read blogs and [one question close to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216555/how-to-implement-database-connection-parameters-validation-in-pentaho-kettle), but have not found a solution to my problem. I have a transformation job setup to extract three tables from 84 DBs to generate one report. My problem is when a DB connection is not available, the whole job stops.

I would like to be able to check DB connections before initializing the job, log errors for inaccessible DBs and create a new dynamic list of successful tests from which I will then run my job. I have used the **check DB connections** step but it still stalls when a connection is false.How can I process my list of DBs, running through to the end, without aborting the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have absolutely used the correct step to check the DB Connections. Now for your question, i would try to explain in parts (hope i am correct):

**Case I: "My problem is when a DB connection is not available, the whole job stops"**

This scenario is obvious. Whenever a step finds any error, it would throw an exception and would stop the entire execution of the Job.

But does it mean that the step "**Check Db connections**" would stop checking the db connections if it gets an error connecting. Answer is **NO**. The Step would complete testing all the connections even if it gets an error in some connection in middle. Try observing the **logs** carefully, it would give you a final consolidated list of all the checked db connections *(check the image below)*:

[image]

I tried testing with 4 db connections out of which i got One error and 3 Success.

Now for the **"Whole Job Stops"** portion: Since the stopping behavior is obvious *(as i have mentioned above)*, what you can do is to pass the flow using "**Error hop**" so that if a job finds an error, it will take the error hop. *Check the image below*:

[image]

Here i have used two hops: One Success and One Error. If the Job fails, it would take the error path *(red colored hop)* else it would take the Success path *(green colored hop)*.

**CASE II: "log errors for inaccessible DBs and create a new dynamic list of successful tests"**

You can either log the errors into a separate log files or table (depends on your requirement) and then read through the log to generate a list of DB connections. Check the image below:

[image]

The output generates a list of Connections along with an Error flag.

```
Y : Failure in connecting to Database
N : successful connection
```

*Note: i have used text file input since i have logged the previous step into a text file instead of database. You can customize as per your req.*

I have placed sample code in [gist](https://gist.github.com/rishuatgithub/1abe68f44932f4fcf58c). You can check for your ref.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation Rishu, that's what I was missing. This is awesome! I had not employed error checking at DBconnections step. Working great now!!